# static broadcast receiver above andorid N

Tags: android

I am creating a custom battery charger animation app.
I want to listen action ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED using Broadcast Receiver. Broadcast will listen even if app is not on mobile stack.I do not want you use Foreground service as it always shows a notification and consume more battery.From android Oreo we can not declare all broadcast receiver on manifest.

In short a want to **listen broadcast above android Oreo while my app in not on mobile stack** and I do not want to use Foreground service.
Please suggest what should I do.

Comment: What does "while my app in not on mobile stack" mean?

Comment: User removes the app from mobile stack